# Custom navbar with changed collpase breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page-J</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

(1) Failed to develop custom navbar 
(2) Failed to change collapse breakpoint

I am using Bootstrap interface and using style.css for customization I am in a middle of designing my navbar which should be transparent on top but after 300px scrollits get solid color i.e. fixed navbar.

Also as I have many pages to show in navbar list so want to change the collapse breakpoint as I have tried all the queries but could achieve the required result.

I have attempted alot of times but failed to develop I appreciate if any one of you help me in this regards.

Here is the Example: https://www.lyft.com/

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You might want to include some of your code here or a plunkr or something, before the downvoters see this. hurry

Comment: So what is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. adding a class that has position:fixed when scroll is greater than a number.

CSS

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}

.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.no-border {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  var $nav = $('nav');
  $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    if(this.scrollY >= 50 && !$nav.hasClass('sticky')){
        $nav.removeClass('no-border');
      $nav.addClass('sticky');
    } else if(this.scrollY < 50 && $nav.hasClass('sticky')){
      $nav.removeClass('sticky');
      $nav.addClass('no-border')
    }
  });
});
```

html I have is kind of long, checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/92wyekh5/1/)

edit: to add transparency